# Greasemonkey error when attempting click() event

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to click a button on a page and I can get the length of the object no problem but when I try to click the item I get this error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... 
 "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  
 location: "JS frame :: resource://greasemonkey/runScript.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 3"  data: no]
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
(function(){
    $('body').append('<input type="button" id="autobop" value="autobop" />');   
    $('#autobop').click(function(){
            //buJmnfJwRG
            alert($('#buJmnfJwRG').length);
            $('#buJmnfJwRG').click(); // error occurs here
            /*
            setInterval(function() {

            }, 2000);*/
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<input type="button" id="autobop" value="autobop" />'); 

        $('#autobop').click(function(){
            //buJmnfJwRG
            alert($('#buJmnfJwRG').length);
            $('#buJmnfJwRG').click();
        });                
});
```

Comment: Note that you do not need either `$(document).ready()` nor `$(function(){ ... })();` in a Greasemonkey script.  GM fires at the right point by default.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the target page. Where did `#buJmnfJwRG` come from, was it on the target page or added by your script?

Unless `#buJmnfJwRG`'s click, event handler was created by your script, using jQuery, you cannot activate it using `$('#buJmnfJwRG').click();` (usually).

Try:

```
$('#autobop').click ( function () {
    //buJmnfJwRG
    alert ( $('#buJmnfJwRG').length );

    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    $('#buJmnfJwRG')[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
} );
```

Comment: no error now but nothing happens and it is not created by my script

Comment: That suggests that the object is now being clicked but that something else is going on.  Link to the target page or save its code to http://pastebin.com/ and link to that.

Comment: i'm just trying to make an auto awesome for http://turntable.fm/mixxxs_fun_house would actually like to make it a bookmarklet so it is browser independant

Comment: Unfortunately, that site is so invasive and crappy that there's no way I'm going to turn off my firewalls enough for it to work.  So, I can't help you anymore with this issue, but they're obviously doing nonstandard and also flash-based stuff -- so, a mere click is not going to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had a dev take a look....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('body').append('<input type="button" id="autobop" value="autobop" />');

$('#autobop').click(function(){

//buJmnfJwRG

alert($('#buJmnfJwRG').length);

$('#buJmnfJwRG').click();

});

});
```

Comment: This is the same as [flux's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495000/) -- which is functionally the same as the OP's code.  It will not fix the problem.